# Branching from ' 0 ' Version

Tags: clearcase

Any one please let me know, How can we create branch from Main 0 -version.

we have Main & The latest Current Version is 50-version. But i want to make branch from O-Version.So that Branch should not ahve any data into it.

Please let me know how can this be done !.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by modifying the config spec of your view (assuming you are in Base ClearCase, not UCM)

```
element .../aNewBranch /main/LATEST
element /path/... /main/0 -mkbranch aNewBranch
```

Note the order:

- first try to select the `LATEST` version of the "`aNewBranch`",
- then select `version 0` with possibility of making a branch if there is a checkout

See [How a ConfigSpec works](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_how_configspec_works.htm) and [Writing a ConfigSpec](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc/r_mstrshp_rqst_config_spec.htm) for more.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by VonC, do not assume that branch with name /main always exist. The type of the "main" branch can be changed, so for example it can be called /head instead.

Comment: Yes, but I very rarely saw that "evil" done. Changing `main` is really-really bad ;)